# How to use fragment with ViewBinding?

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewbinding

I want to create a fragment with ViewBinding but my code not working. I read [ViewBinding Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) but my fragment not show.
This is my code:

fragment_player.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test fragment"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_player"
    class="com.test.plo.view.PlayerFragment"
    android:name="com.test.plo.view.PlayerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

PlayerFragment.java

```
 public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

   private FragmentPlayerBinding fragmentPlayerBinding;

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       fragmentPlayerBinding = FragmentPlayerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
       View view = fragmentPlayerBinding.getRoot();
       return view;
   }

  @Override
  public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
      fragmentPlayerBinding = null;
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi checkout this post completely explaining view binding with activity| fragment |Recycler Views| customview [Androidbites|ViewBinding](https://chetangupta.net/viewbinding/)

Comment: The best way I see here is to wrap the fragment inside a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
    }
}
```

in your app build.gradle?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, In your app level put the below lines of code

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1          
        versionName "1.0"       
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    //Enable View Bindings to true
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Then add new fragment in your project by Right click "File" -> New -> Fragment -> select Blank Fragment(or any fragment you want). This will create your fragment class file along with an xml file associated with it.
I have created blank fragment with name "HomeFragment.kt", and the name of its xml file is "fragment_home.xml".

In My xml file, I have added one textview and Button(you can define your widgets here-a design layout), And code will look like below.

**"fragment_home.xml"**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



  <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/mTv_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Home Fragment"
                    android:textColor="@color/main_black"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />


 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/mBtn_homeButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Click Here!"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20sp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:cornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp" />

  </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And finally in your fragment class, You can bind these attributes using viewBinding.
**"HomeFragment.kt"**

```
    class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    // view binding will create an Class for your xml file, you can use it directly by this "FragmentHomeBinding" as my xml file name is "fragment_home.xml" 
 // create a variable of your xml binding class
    private lateinit var binding : FragmentHomeBinding 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (arguments!=null) {
            Log.i(tag, "onCreate: ")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        //val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // observe your text change by using viewModel
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            //you can use your view/widgets by using the binding object like this --- 
            binding.mTvTitle.text = it
        })

       // button click event -- using viewBinding 
       binding.mBtnHomeButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hello..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
       

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**Cheers..!**